# Memory management in iOS - I can't find out how to release memory

Tags: ios, memory-management, ios4

I'm using iOS 4 and I have some memory management problems that I don't understand. I will try to simplify the code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    NSMutableArray *buttonArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (int i = 0; i < [othercollection count]; i++)
    {
        // Push objects to button array
    }

    self.buttonSliderView = [[ButtonSliderView alloc] initWithButtons:
        buttonArray];
    [buttonArray release];
    [self.view addSubview:self.buttonSliderView];
    [buttonSliderView release];
}

- (void) viewDidAppear 
{
     if ([buttonSliderView.menuButtons count] > 0)
     {
         // ...
     }
}
```

In `ButtonSliderView.m`:

```
- (id)initWithButtons:(NSMutableArray *)buttonArray
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self)
    {
        menuButtons = buttonArray;
    }
 }
```

I have an error in the first line of `viewDidAppear`. `menuButtons` were released. How can I fix this? Which is the correct solution?

If I change button array declaration to this:

```
NSMutableArray* buttonArray = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease];
```

...and remove the `release` sentence, it crashes too. If I remove the `release` sentence and don't `autorelease`, it works, but there are memory leaks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you omit the setter and assign *menuButtons* property directly. Try this:

```
-(id) initWithButtons:(NSMutableArray*)buttonArray  {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        [self setMenuButtons:buttonArray];
    }
}
```

You didn't show how the *menuButtons* property is declared, but I assume it is:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray* menuButtons;
```

This will retain *menuButtons* automatically for you whenever you set it with the setter. If you have your property declared like this:

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSArray* menuButtons;
```

then you need to retain the array manually:

```
-(id) initWithButtons:(NSMutableArray*)buttonArray  {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        menuButtons = [buttonArray retain];
    }
}
```

Comment: I used the setter and everything worked. 
Why isn't the same self.menubuttons as [self setMenuButtons... ?

Comment: It is the same, but in your code you directly assigned the ivar like this: `menuButtons = buttonArray;`

Answer (score 1):

`ButtonSliderView` may be still using that object (as opposed to grabbing the contents and releasing it). Don't assume it's a memory leak just for that reason alone.

Comment: But I allocated it. Shouldnt I release the object?